# How to position a HTML button with link?

Tags: html, css, button, styles, positioning

```
<form method="get" action=https://www.wwf.de/spenden-helfen/allgemeine-spende>
    <button type="submit">Spenden </button>
```

This is my problem the button is just spawning randomly but i need it to be on a spesific place on my website. (Im new with it)

I tried other buttons but i coud not use them as a link. I tried style= in many ways but nothing did work

Comment: the button = <form method="get" action=https://www.wwf.de/spenden-helfen/allgemeine-spende>
  <button type="submit">Spenden </button>

Comment: “*The button is just spawning randomly*” - that’s rarely how html elements are created, why, and how, is this element “spawning randomly”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple to do this with `css`.

Button code example:

```
<button class="my-btn">Click here!</button>
```

Css code:

```
.my-btn {
    position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 250px;
}
```

This way the button will be placed from 250px at the top left of the page.

Or simple do a inline code:

```
<button style="position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 250px">Click Here!</button>
```

Comment: why do all the next buttons have the same funktion? my code=

Comment: <form method="get" action=https://www.wwf.de/spenden-helfen/allgemeine-spende>
  <button style="position: absolute; top: 1750px; left: 1320px">spenden</button>  But this butoon does not work<style type="text/css">
   $("button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top},
     'slow');
   });</style>
   <button style="position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 120px">spendennn</button

Comment: @ProarFirst if my answer helped, please mark as answer clicking in ✅